# 2d dynamic array in structure

Tags: c, arrays

I'm learning for school and I found exam task:
"Create struct with fields:
 2 integers, 
 two-dimensional flexible array (double or float) "

I did something like that:

```
    struct my_struct{
     int firstField;
     int secondField;
     int columns;
     int rows;
     double tab[columns][rows];
}

struct my_struct sample = {2, 2, 5, 4, {0.0}}
```

But it does not work.How should I create struct like that?

Comment: The task is not worded precisely. It is impossible to have a dynamic 2D array within a structure. It is possible to have a pointer to one, though...

Comment: You can't refer to struct members as ordinary variables.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Maybe they mean a flexible array member.

Comment: @Barmar Can it be 2d? I guess only with one dimension fixed

Comment: @EugeneSh yes I should wrote flexible array member

Comment: "does not work" is not an acceptable problem description.

Comment: "two-dimensional flexible array" --> I suspect only a 1D flexible array member  is allowed. `struct my_struct{
 int firstField;
 int secondField;
 int columns;
 int rows;
 double tab[][];
};` erorrs with "error: array type has incomplete element type 'double[]'"

Comment: Empirically, GCC and Clang both allow a FAM like `int fam[][32];` with a fixed second dimension.  You have to work harder to get a 2D VLA with both dimensions variable.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

A `struct` cannot have a 2D VLA *variable logic array* nor a 2D FAM, *flexible array member* like with member `double tab[columns][rows];`.  A `struct` can have a final  of 1 dimensional FAM.

Code can get close to OP's goal of "Create struct with fields: 2 integers, two-dimensional flexible array (double or float) " by using a flexible array member that is an array of `double *`.

```
struct my_struct {
  int columns;
  int rows;
  double *tab[/* row */];
};
```

This makes `tab`, not a 2D array but a 1D array of `double *`.  This is  usable like a 2D array with the `[][]` syntax.

---

First allocate not only memory for `my_struct`, but also for the appended array of `double *` pointers.  Then allocate memory for the `double` array for each pointer.

As with all allocations, good to test if the allocation succeeded.  Following simple uses `assert(p);`

I replaced working code with some TBD to allow for OP's learning experience.

```
struct my_struct *my_struct_alloc(int columns, int rows) {
  struct my_struct *p = malloc(sizeof *p + sizeof *(p->tab) * TBD);
  assert(p);
  p->columns = TBD;
  p->rows = TBD;
  for (int r = 0; r < p->rows; r++) {
    p->tab[r] = malloc(sizeof *(p->tab[r]) * TBD);
    assert(p->tab[r]);
    for (int c = 0; c < p->columns; c++) {  // sample, fill array w/illustrative data
      static int count = 0;
      p->tab[r][c] = count++; // Access like a 2D array
    }
  }
  return p;
}

void my_struct_print(struct my_struct *p) {
  for (int r = 0; r < p->rows; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < p->columns; c++) {
      printf("%.0f ", p->tab[r][c]);  // Access like a 2D array
    }
    puts("");
  }
}

void my_struct_free(struct my_struct *p) {
  if (p) {
    for (int r = 0; r < p->rows; r++) {
      free(p->tab[r]);
    }
  }
  free(p);
}

int main() {
  struct my_struct *p = my_struct_alloc(2, 3);
  my_struct_print(p);
  my_struct_free(p);
}
```

Output

```
0 1 
2 3 
4 5
```

Comment: Other improvements would include using `size_t rows` rather than `int rows`, allowing for `rows*columns== 0`.  More efficient allocation scheme (1 or 2 allocs vs 1 + rows allocs), using `const` when printing, etc.